# Hangman game wont print same letter

Tags: javascript

I have a question about my game. It seems like I can only get one letter to print instead how many there are in a word. For instance, "star wars" looks like "star wr".

```js
//array of Star Wars Names
var words = ["star wars",
  "senator organa",
  "boba fett",
  "chewbacca",
  "luke skywalker",
  "darth vader",
  "lando calrissian",
  "anakin skywalker",
  "padme amidala"
];

//Declared variables
var rightLetter = [];
var wrongLetter = [];
var underScore = [];
var underScore = [];
var randomWords = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
var chosenWords = words[randomWords];
var starWarsNames = document.getElementsByClassName("Star_Wars_words");
var correctGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("rightGuess");
var incorrectGuess = document.getElementsByClassName("wrongGuess");

//random word array

console.log(chosenWords);

function generateUnderscore() {
  for (i = 0; i < chosenWords.length; i++) {
    underScore.push("_");
  }
  return underScore;
}

//Game Loop
document.addEventListener("keypress", letterPressed);
//letter function
function letterPressed(event) {
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if (chosenWords.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
    rightLetter.push(letter);
    underScore[chosenWords.indexOf(letter)] = letter;
    starWarsNames[0].innerHTML = underScore.join(" ");
    correctGuess[0].innerHTML = rightLetter;
    if (underScore.join(" ") == chosenWords) {
      alert("The force is strong with you!");
    }
  } else {
    wrongLetter.push(letter);
    incorrectGuess[0].innerHTML = wrongLetter;
  }
}

console.log(rightLetter);
console.log(wrongLetter);
console.log(starWarsNames);
```

```html
<div class="Star_Wars_words">

</div>
<div class="rightGuess">

</div>
<div class="wrongGuess">

</div>
```

Comment: *I can only get one letter to print*... *For instance, "star wars" looks like "star wr"*, that's clearly more than one letter? So what are you talking about?

Comment: @MattBurland He's asking: "My final string seems to only accept the first occurrence of a specific letter and ignores subsequent ones"

Comment: He meant the a and the s only printed once

Comment: I meant to say that if there is more than one letter in the word that repeats, it will only print the first one.

Comment: indexOf(string) returns only the _first_ location of the match.  You never do anything to handle matches beyond the first.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Then after finding the first occurrence, you need to continue searching the rest of the string until there are no more occurrences. Note the optional `fromIndex` parameter for `indexOf`.

Comment: Matt Burland, @JBC, Thank you, looking this up right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `letterPressed` function, you can reorganize it to check for multiple instances. For example:

```
var idx = 0;
idx = chosenWords.indexOf(letter, idx);
if (idx == -1) {
    wrongLetter.push(letter);
    incorrectGuess[0].innerHTML = wrongLetter;
    return;
}
while (idx > -1) {
    rightLetter.push(letter);
    underScore[idx] = letter;
    starWarsNames[0].innerHTML = underScore.join(" ");
    correctGuess[0].innerHTML = rightLetter;
    if(underScore.join(" ") == chosenWords) {
        alert("The force is strong with you!");
    }
    idx = chosenWords.indexOf(letter, ++idx);
}
```

So the difference is that if a letter is found (`idx > -1`) then you will process it as you were before, but then you will update `idx` with the next index of the letter.